# Swarm robotics facility in ROS?

Tags: gazebo, simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am interested in swarm robotics - I know about swarm simulation in Stage (ver 3.X.X and above - this works when I use stage and fails for stageros). I guess such swarm simulations may be possible in Gazebo (?).

Does ROS provide for any platform/package/software for swarm and/or multi-robot simulation ?

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

**Reference**

1. [Richard T. Vaughan. Massively Multi-Robot Simulations in Stage. Swarm Intelligence, 2(2-4):189-208, 2008](http://autonomy.cs.sfu.ca/bib/Author/doc/vaughan_si08.pdf)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11192/swarm-robotics-facility-in-ros-?/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2011-09-13

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-09-23**:
@kwc : Multimaster support, planned for in Fuerte - can that be potentially an answer to this question ?

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-09-21**:
@kwc : All right ! ....... hope hopen, I have added another screenshot ! ....

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-20**:
The question is appropriate, there just aren't any answers.  Don't worry about cleaning it up.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-09-20**:
@kwc : Okay, if it doesn't really suit the topics at answers.ros (I had to create the tag of swarm) then should we scrap it ?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-19**:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support "The question was seen. If you didn't get a response then likely nobody has had time to answer you. Alternatively, it could be that nobody knows the answer."

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-09-17**:
Others can vote your question up.  Note that asking for a confirmation that there's no other solution in the entire eco-system is not really possible, for no one is familiar with every ROS package in the world.  No reply likely means that there's not another version.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-09-16**:
@kwc : Hi Ken, I am not getting much of a response on this question. Is there a award of a 'bounty' at answers.ros as in stackoverflow and superuser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think gazebo might be a bit overkill performance-wise although it is theoretically possible. Do you need gazebo for simulation?

There is a [stage](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage) package for ROS if you were looking for that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-09-13**:
@dornhege : Yep - Stage works good, as of now my means for swarm robotics simulations. Any other software/packages will be most welcome.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-09-13**:
I was only referring to the fact that stage is supported in ROS directly. I'm not aware of other packages, but someone else might know some.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-09-13**:
@dornhege : I know about Stage (see the reference) - I am currently using Stage. I wanted to check out if ROS has any other leverages for swarm robotics.